# call route in another route (cron job testing)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have route like this:

```
Route::get('cron_job/{param1}/{param2?}', function($param1 = NULL, $param2 = NULL)
{
    //do something here;
    echo "Im'm here with param". $param1;
});
```

I use this route for cron jobs and it works OK.

But now, I want to try it with another route to test it with loop, like this:

```
Route::get('test_cron_job', function()
{
    do {
        $param = 1;
        // here I just want to call http://my_app.local/cron_job/$param1 
        $param++;
    } while ($param <10)
});
```

How to do it? In cronjob I use:

```
links -dump http://my_app.local/cron_job/$param1
```

But how to call it inside another route in route.php to test it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let try:

```
Route::get('test_cron_job', function()
{
   do {
      $param1 = 1;
      // here I just want to call http://my_app.local/cron_job/$param1
      redirect('/cron_job/'.$param1);
     $param++;
   } while ($param <10)
});
```

Comment: if you are redirecting to a url, then how you are going to complete your loop??

Answer (score 2):

You can use file_get_content(url);

```
$file = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/{$param1}", false, $context);
```